# Loading of angular view glitch for the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a user clicks a hyperlink and I change the ng-view, the first time it takes more time but next time onwards, the switch from one view to another is smooth without any delay.
I have put together a sample plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cINyIOpJBEAsa2pUk3tP?p=preview

app.js from that plunker looks like:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate'
]);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/ShowOrder/:orderId', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/show_order.html',
      controller: 'ShowOrderController'
    });
  }
]);


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {


  $scope.order_id = $routeParams.orderId;
});

sampleApp.animation('.content',
  function() {
    return {
      enter: function(element, done) {
        var delay = $('.content').length === 2 ? 600 : 0; // if there are 2 .content (ngView) delay entrance, so the 1st can leave
        $(element).css({
          opacity: 0 // set the stage
        });
        $(element).delay(delay).animate({ // animate the opacity with delay if needed
          opacity: 1
        }, 600, done);
      },
      leave: function(element, done) {

        $(element).css({
          position: 'absolute', // use position absolute so the element won't jump down
          opacity: 1 // set the stage
        });
        $(element).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 600, done);

      }
    }
  }
)
```

In my enterprise app, this initial delay is more visible to the user due to more data and initialization of variables that I do.

Any way to make it smoother?

Comment: I am confused are you asking about the 600ms delay that you put on the animation?

Comment: @ewahner 600ms is the switching time between views which is ok. If u reload the page with ctrl+R and then click a link, it takes more than 600ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial delay is caused by route template request. It can be eliminated by caching the templates early,

```
sampleApp.run(function ($http, $templateCache) {
  $http.get('templates/show_order.html', { cache: $templateCache });
});
```

Or by concatenating the templates during the build phase by means of [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) or [grunt-html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js).

Comment: looks cool. I will give it a try and post if it worked for me

Comment: That code works on my complex app with multiple scopes without any glitch code. Thanks a ton